# No Overload For 'button10_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'

Tags: c#

Clicking a button from windows form it doesn't work.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, ref Graphics g, 
    ref EVFDataSet evfDataSet, ref int iWidth, ref int iHeight)
    {
      
        int cx = iWidth;
        int cy = iHeight;

        int iw = evfDataSet.sizeJpegLarge.width;
        int ih = evfDataSet.sizeJpegLarge.height;
         
        long left = evfDataSet.zoomRect.x;
        long top = evfDataSet.zoomRect.y;

        long x = left * cx / iw;
        long y = top * cy / ih;

        long width = evfDataSet.zoomRect.width * cx / iw;
        long height = evfDataSet.zoomRect.height * cy / ih;

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255));
        pen.Width = 3;

        int str = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value);
        for (int i = 0; i < str; i++)
        {
            varas.recty.DrawRectangle(pen, x + 1, y + 1, width + 1, height + 1);
        }
    }
```

When using this method the code works. But that isn't possible when trying to click the button.

Comment: You can't just make up your own method signature for an event handler. Use the normal signature and capture the other values some other way, like in class fields or properties.

Comment: What is `varas.recty`? What is this code actually supposed to be achieving? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation.

Comment: How to add ref. on button click event (ref EVFDataSet evfDataSet ). EVFDataSet is a  other   .cs file structure .

Answer (score 0):

You can't just arbitrarily add parameters to an event handler. When a `Button` raises its `Click` event, it will pass arguments to the `sender` and `e` parameters. Where exactly do you think the arguments for those other parameters are going to come from? Get rid of them if you want that method to handle a `Click` event. If you want to call the method explicitly yourself then that's fine, but then it can't handle that event and the first two parameters are pointless. If you need to write two separate methods - one for the event handler and one to call yourself, possibly from the event handler - then write two different methods.